# Unable to use icomoon icons

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, uicontrol

I am using [icomoon](https://icomoon.io) for icons but some icons are not appear.Here is my problem.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJNYS.png)

Instead of number 3 icon, number 4 icon should be appear, but I am unable to do this.I am using **.ico-number4**  class.Here is my code.

```
.icon-number:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
.icon-number2:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-number3:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-number4:before {
    content: "\e603";
}
.icon-number5:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-number6:before {
    content: "\e605";
}
.icon-number7:before{
    content: "\e607";
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make sure you are using the right classes. If you accidentally used `.icon-number-3` instead of 4, then it wouldn't work.